# A computing trick to calculate for e.g number of boxes required to place N objects given each box can hold M objects?

Tags: c++

As a part of a recent topcoder SRM problem we had to compute number of buses "B" required to carry "N" people given that each bus has "S" seats.

What is the smartest way to compute this in C++?
The obvious way is to do:

```
if(N%S==0){B=N/S;}
else{ B=N/S + 1;}
```

^ ALL VARIABLES ARE INTEGERS, N AND S ASSIGNED APPROPRIATE VALUES

However I cant understand the logic behind the following code which is one particular topcoder user's solution which I was checking out;

```
   B = (N + (S-1))/S;
```

How does this work?

Comment: Try it with some test values (e.g. S = 4, and N = 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), and you'll see how it works.

Comment: I think your `if` condition for your "obvious" method ought to be `N % S == 0`.  As for which solution is superior?  Difficult to say.  I think in practice nobody would notice the difference in performance between the two unless it happened to be in the middle of some performance critical loop.

Comment: Sorry, Corrected it. So it is useful mostly for these coding competitions where you have to type quickly.

Also, I found one more method of doing the same thing:

  `B= (N/S) + (N%S!=0)`

The second term on the RHS will be casted to an int during the addition.

Comment: Yes, that's a useful and very widely known approach to rounding up.  Did you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
B = (N + (S-1))/S;
```

is a common rounding trick. We know that in integer division, the remainder is cut-off, essentially what `floor` does. In this case, we enforce a `ceil` operation by adding S-1 first.

This is similiar to the common way of rounding floating point numbers:

```
n = floor(n + 0.5);
```